# UWP ValueConverter returns System._COMObject

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I'm creating unit tests for a UWP (Windows 10) project. I'm testing a Value Converter. The 
converter should return, if all is OK, the SelectedItems property of a ListView control. 
This is the converter:

```
internal class MultipleSelectionChangedConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
  {
    var listView = parameter as ListView;

    if (listView != null)
       return listView.SelectedItems;

    return new ListView();
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

I'm trying to check the results in this Unit test:

```
[UITestMethod] 
[TestCategory("Multiple Selection Changed Converter")]
public void ShouldSetSelectedItems()
{
  IList<object> results = null;

  var listToSetSelectedItems = new ListView
  {
    ItemsSource = new List<string> { "item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"     },
    SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.Multiple,
  };
  listToSetSelectedItems.SelectedItems.Add("item 1");
  listToSetSelectedItems.SelectedItems.Add("item 2");

  results = (IList<object>)converter.Convert(null, typeof(IList<object>), listToSetSelectedItems, string.Empty);

  Assert.IsTrue(results != null);
  Assert.IsTrue(results.Count == 2);
  //Assert.IsTrue(results.Contains("item 1"));
  //Assert.IsTrue(results.Contains("item 2"));
}
```

The  variable should contain the SelectedItems property, which is of type IList. Instead, it comes back set with a System._COMObjects value.
Also, I get an "Information not available, no symbols loaded for Windows.UI.Xaml.dll" message. What can I do to get the correct type for the SelectedItems property ?

Thanks

Comment: *"The variable should contain the SelectedItems property"* - Which variable? *"which is of type IList"* - aren't you using `IList<object>`? *"it comes back set with a System._COMObjects"* - Sure this isn't a `System.__COMObject`?

Comment: Test failed, that converter is borken.  Write a bug report.

Answer (score 3):

In this part of your code

```
var listView = parameter as ListView;

    if (listView != null)
       return listView.SelectedItems;

    return new ListView();
```

you are returning list of selected items when listview is not null. however when it is null you are returning a new listview itself. Don't you think return type should be same.